# Error signing a sample XML using Xades4J: ReferenceNotInitializedException: Cannot resolve element with ID

Tags: java, xades4j

I'm trying to sign a simple XML using Xades4J using [this](https://gist.github.com/JohnnyJosep/29cd545db3d0b7abd23279b56d4db194) example, but I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" xades4j.XAdES4jXMLSigException:
>   Cannot resolve element with ID
>   at xades4j.production.SignerBES.sign(SignerBES.java:277)
>   at xades4j.production.SignerBES.sign(SignerBES.java:130)
>   at xmlSigner.Main.main(Main.java:63)
>   Caused by: 
>   org.apache.xml.security.signature.ReferenceNotInitializedException: Cannot resolve element with ID
>   Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID
>   at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.getContentsBeforeTransformation(Reference.java:437)
>   at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.calculateDigest(Reference.java:722)
>   at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.generateDigestValue(Reference.java:414)
>   at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Manifest.generateDigestValues(Manifest.java:205)
>   at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.sign(XMLSignature.java:628)
>   at xades4j.production.SignerBES.sign(SignerBES.java:273)
>   ... 2 more
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException:
>   Cannot resolve element with ID    at
>   org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.implementations.ResolverFragment.engineResolveURI(ResolverFragment.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver.resolve(ResourceResolver.java:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.getContentsBeforeTransformation(Reference.java:435)
>     ... 7 more

My code is this

```
package xmlSigner;
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import xades4j.algorithms.EnvelopedSignatureTransform;
import xades4j.production.DataObjectReference;
import xades4j.production.SignedDataObjects;
import xades4j.production.XadesBesSigningProfile;
import xades4j.production.XadesSigner;
import xades4j.properties.DataObjectDesc;
import xades4j.providers.KeyingDataProvider;
import xades4j.providers.impl.FileSystemKeyStoreKeyingDataProvider;
import xades4j.providers.impl.DirectPasswordProvider;
import xades4j.providers.impl.FirstCertificateSelector;
import xades4j.utils.DOMHelper;

public class Main {

        private static final String CERT_FOLDER = "C:\\Users\\...";
        private static final String CERT        = "keystore.p12";
        //private static final String KEY_STORE   = "KeyStorage";
        private static final String PASS        = "mypass"; //the same in cert and keystorage

        //private static final String TSA_URL     = "http://XXX.XXX.XXX/ts.inx";
        //private static final String TSA_USER    = "XXXXXXXX";
        //private static final String TSA_PASS    = "XXXXXXXX";

        //private static final String UNSIGNED    = "C:/Test/sign-verify/unsigned.xml";
        private static final String SIGNED      = "C:\\Users\\...\\FLUSSO_A_signed.xml";
        //private static final String SIGNEDT     = "C:/Test/sign-verify/signed-t-bes.xml";    
        //private static final String VERIFY      = "C:/Test/sign-verify/verify-bes.txt";
        //private static final String VERIFYT     = "C:/Test/sign-verify/verify-t-bes.txt";
        private static final String DOCUMENT    = "C:\\Users\\..\\FLUSSO_A.xml";
        //private static final String DOCSIGNED   = "C:/Test/sign-verify/signed.bes.xml";

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder()
                    .parse(new File(DOCUMENT));
            Element elem = doc.getDocumentElement();
            DOMHelper.useIdAsXmlId(elem);


            KeyingDataProvider kdp = new FileSystemKeyStoreKeyingDataProvider(
                    "pkcs12",
                    CERT_FOLDER + CERT,
                    new FirstCertificateSelector(),
                    new DirectPasswordProvider(PASS),
                    new DirectPasswordProvider(PASS),
                    true);
            // here I tried also EManifest (the XML root tag) and name (since elem has a "name" attribute)
            DataObjectDesc obj = new DataObjectReference("#" + elem.getAttribute("Id")) 
                    .withTransform(new EnvelopedSignatureTransform());
            SignedDataObjects dataObjs = new SignedDataObjects().withSignedDataObject(obj);

            XadesSigner signer = new XadesBesSigningProfile(kdp).newSigner();
            signer.sign(dataObjs, elem); // fails here

            /*TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);        
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(SIGNED));
            transformer.transform(source, result);*/
        }
    }
```

The XML is an example document for customs processes and can be found [here](https://www.adm.gov.it/portale/documents/20182/5550853/FLUSSO_A.xml/ef6675a0-9a93-425a-bb15-f00a45add9cc).
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is not needed create the ID. You can do this:

DataObjectDesc dataObjRef = new DataObjectReference("").withTransform(new EnvelopedSignatureTransform());

summarizing pass "" to DataObjectReference

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The root tag of my XML looks like this

```
<EManifest xmlns="http://www.iso.org/28005-ITA" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.iso.org/28005-ITA">
```

adding the attribute to the tag (specifically `Id="test"` ) solved the issue.

Now my root tag looks like this

```
<EManifest xmlns="http://www.iso.org/28005-ITA" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.iso.org/28005-ITA" Id="test">
```